# Microsoft Visual Studio has detected mismatched installed versions of language resources

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and every time I try to execute it, show me the next message:

> Microsoft Visual Studio has detected mismatched installed versions of language resources. This may 
>   happen for instance when different versions of the product (Beta, RC, RTM) are installed 
>   for different languages.
>
> Please uninstall all older versions and language packs or upgrade them all to the latest available 
>   version. Until the problem is fixed Microsoft Visual Studio will not start.

**Summary:**

I had previously installed Visual Studio 2015 Community RC. Before install Professional i did unistall Community RC.

I did uninstall all language packages in Control Panel-Uninstall Programs.
I did uninstall all language packages in Control Panel-Update Packages.

And still doesn't work.

Comment: nobody has a hint? I have the same problem and I can't find how to fix it

Answer (score 7):

the same issue and full answer is here: [VS2015 does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474002/vs2015-does-not-start/39871907#39871907)

short answer:

1. open regedit
2. goto

   1. in case VS:
      `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\General`
   2. in case SSMS: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0\General`
3. set the value of `UILanguage` parameter to 0

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all versions of Visual Studio using https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases

and then reinstall visual studio and continue.