# VS2015 does not start

Tags: visual-studio-2015

VS2013 community edition and VS2015 RC was installed on my Windows 7.

I have uninstalled VS2015 RC, VS2013 and installed VS2015 Proffesional.
After start it displays message:

```
"Microsoft Visual Studio has detected mismatched installed versions of language resources.
This may happen for instances when different versions of the product (Beta, RC, RTM) are installed for different languages.
Please uninstall an older versions and language packs or upgrade them all to the latest available version. Until the problem is fixed Microsoft Visual Studio will not start."
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with SSMS (SQL Management Studio).

I've solved that issue like this:

1. open regedit
2. goto `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\General`
3. set the value of `UILanguage` parameter to 0

---

in my case the path in regedit was a little bit different:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0\General`

and after SSMS restart everything was fine - that error dissapeared

worked for Management Studio!

I think for VS the same solution.

Comment: any idea what to do if the UILanguage is rese to the initial value when I try to reopen visual studio?

Comment: @AnotherGeek Same here

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall all your old versions of Visual studio.

Comment: Ununstalled all, then installed only VS2015 Pro, the same error.

Comment: @chrish - based on the question that's already been attempted.